# Is possible to use %s string format in Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, formatting

I need to work with .arb files for internalization in Flutter, and I am interesting is possible to use string format with %s, and integer format with %d in Flutter, such in Java, C#, Python, etc.
I want for example this string in app_en.arb

```
{
"ocrMessage": "User with name %s found in the database. Would you like to select and edit them?"
}
```

I was searching Flutter documentation and Google, but I did not find anything about formatting strings in Flutter, only string interpolation, eg:

```
var myName = "Darko";
Print("Your name is $myName");
```

Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Darko

Answer (score 1):

[sprintf: ^6.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/sprintf) Use this package

```
  var me = {
    "ocrMessage":
        "User with name %s found in the database. Would you like to select and edit them?"
  };
  print(sprintf(me["ocrMessage"].toString(), [100]));
```

**Output:**

```
User with name 100 found in the database. Would you like to select and edit them?
```

Answer (score 1):

you're right, the most common way to format a string in Dart/Flutter is using a string interpolation. As outlined by @lava, there are packages like `sprintf` to add your desired behavior. But as I
understand your question, you would like to find a way to insert a dynamic value into your translations. If so, arb files provide a simple way to define placeholders that you can use in your string. The following is an example for your `ocrMessage` with a varying `firstName`:

```
"ocrMessage": "User with name {firstName} found in the database. Would you like to select and edit them?",
"@ocrMessage": {
  "description": "A user's first name",
  "placeholders": {
    "firstName": {}
  }
}
```

After running the code generator, you'll get access to your translation by using the following (assuming that your localization delegate class is named AppLocalizations):

`AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ocrMessage("Darko")`

As the parameters of the generated code will be of type Object, you can add basically anything you want (except null) that can be transformed to a string.

Hope this solves your question!

Comment: Do I need to add placeholders in each .arb file where I want interpolation, or only in app_en.arb, because I am translating the app from English to several languages.

Comment: As far as I know, you only need to specify the  placeholders in your main arb (like the English one). Then you can use it in other files too without redefining it as long as you are using the same name for it (like firstName in my example). But, it will also work if you add your placeholder in other arb files again. Sometimes this can make sense if you'd like to have a translated placeholder name.